# How to call $( document ).ready() jQuery function with in ngAfterViewInit() on Component class using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular-components

The code is

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.loadScript('app/homepage/template-scripts.js');       


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular let you avoid this jquery dependency with lifecycle events:

(ordered by lifecycle)

-ngOnChanges
-ngOnInit
-ngDoCheck
-ngAfterContentInit
-ngAfterContentChecked
-ngAfterViewInit
-ngAfterViewChecked
-ngOnDestroy

if you want to use the jquery function `.ready`, you should import jquery as dependency in your angular project, then import the relative module in your `.ts` file and call it inside of ngAfterViewInit:

```js
// In the console
// First install jQuery
npm install --save jquery
// and jQuery Definition
npm install -D @types/jquery

-----

import $ from 'jquery';
//

ngAfterViewInit() {
// other stuffs

if ($.ready()) {
    console.log('ready');
  }
}
```

my code above works.

But i want to explain you that is bad practise, because you are going to put logic inside existing angular lifecycle logic.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Hope this helped